# Trading book estimation

Tags: finance, trading

Do you have any idea/hints how could I estimate the size of the trading book of a particular bank relying solely on its annual financial report?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Regulatory bodies usually require distinction between trading and banking book for all positions. Have a look at this [page](https://annualreport.deutsche-bank.com/2014/ar/management-report/risk-report/market-risk/trading-book.html)